# Is it guaranteed that there exists a smooth solution of the Laplace equation for a smooth source term?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle with periodic boundary conditions. Also, let $\phi$ be a smooth function on $V$.

Then, is it true that there must exist a smooth $\Phi$ on $V$ such that
\begin{equation}
\Delta \Phi=\phi
\end{equation}
or is it false?

How about the case in which the boundary condition is Dirichlet instead of periodic?

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth"? Be precise.

Comment: It means $C^\infty$

Comment: You may find this useful:
http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/Laplace_12.pdf